# Substring of a Unicode string with text-direction marks

Tags: string, unicode

I want to split a given Unicode string into two parts (“head” and “tail”) at grapheme cluster number *i*. Example applications include:

- I'm integrating with Twitter and want to extract the first 140 grapheme clusters of a title to share as a tweet
- I'm building a blog and you want to show the first 300 grapheme clusters in a list, hiding the rest under “Read more”.
- I'm building a speed reading app and want to extract individual words of a string.
- I'm building an app that animates parts of the string based on special markup.
- (countless more)

Suppose I have a library function to split a string into grapheme clusters. (Could be Cocoa NSString's built-in grapheme cluster enumeration, forgetting for a moment that it craps out on the new Unicode 6 country indicators, or [grapheme-breaker](https://github.com/devongovett/grapheme-breaker) in JavaScript, or a makeshift regexp approach that happens to work on the expected inputs, or something else.)

The naïve approach is to split the string into an array of grapheme clusters, then take a subarray from element *i* to element *j*, then join the subarray to form a new string.

And that's, in fact, what I have been doing all the time so far.

However, I've realized that if the string contains text-direction marks, the task is anything but simple:

1. The reading order might not match the writing order.
2. If a text-direction mark happens to go into the head part, the tail part would be interpreted incorrectly, so you need to somehow restore it in the tail part as well.

I'm wondering:

1. Is there an existing, reliable algorithm to deal with this? (needless to say, an alphabet search came out empty)
2. Are there any existing libraries to handle this?
3. Does it even make sense to formulate the task in terms of grapheme cluster index in the presence of varying text directions?
4. Overall, what's the best way to approach the applications outlined in the beginning of the question?

The question is platform- and language-agnostic; it's a common problem for all of them, and I'm interested in a large variety anyway (JavaScript, Ruby, Python, Objective-C/Swift, Go, Java, .NET at least).

Comment: For question 3, I do not think the text direction matters in a outline application. Because text with direction marks is rare. In my application, I just grab the first paragraph, or the first 100 codepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the writing order of the text—that's a problem for the code that actually typesets and renders the text using the [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/). If you're just splitting text, your job is much simpler (comparatively). [Chapter 23](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/ch23.pdf) of the Unicode Standard says:

> #### Stateful Format Controls
>
> The Unicode Standard contains a small number
> of paired stateful controls. These characters are used in pairs, with
> an initiating character (or sequence) and a terminating character.
> Even when these characters are not supported by a particular
> implementation, complications can arise due to their paired nature.
> Whenever text is cut, copied, pasted, or deleted, these characters can
> become unpaired. To avoid this problem, ideally both any copied text
> and its context (site of a deletion, or target of an insertion) would
> be modified so as to maintain all pairings that were in effect for
> each piece of text. This process can be quite complicated, however,
> and is not often done—or is done incorrectly if attempted.

There are only three sets of paired control characters (and two deprecated sets) that you need to worry about as of Unicode 8.0:

- Bidirectional overrides: `U+202A`–`U+202E`
- Annotation characters: `U+FFF9`–`U+FFFB`
- Musical beams and slurs: `U+1D173`–`U+1D17A`

Their related sections in the Unicode Standard explain how these characters are intended to work.

In most cases—and especially for those you describe—simply ensuring that the bidirectional state is consistent and preserved for each substring is probably sufficient. The handling of annotations and musical features is quite application-specific, and their use outside of those applications is *very* rare.

As for your other questions, grapheme clusters are the correct way to working with text like that (although, note that [Twitter counts code points](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/counting-characters)). Determining text direction is a complicated process, but it's mostly a property of the characters themselves and not of any annotations or surrounding text. The Unicode [word boundary algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries) will also probably be useful to you.